# How to draw shapes on a blank image exactly how they were in source image by using OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, contour

I have a source image (black background and white objects) and I want to find the contours from that image, create a new blank image with black background and draw the contours on that image one by one as they were in the source image. I know how to find contours and create the blank image, but I'm having trouble with drawing the contours the same way they were in the source image. I get some results, but the color filling sometimes fills incorrectly or just doesn't look right. I have been thinking if I should get the inverse of the contours and fill that, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's possible. What I basically want to do, is to draw the shapes of an image on a video one by one.

Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import statistics as st


# Function to denoise images
def denoise(contours):
    # Array that contains contours that will be removed
    filtered_cont = []
    sample = []
    # Gathering sample
    for contour in contours:
        sample.append(len(contour))
    # Calculating standard deviation
    stdev = st.stdev(sample)
    for contour in contours:
        # Comparing contour length to standard deviation divided by 3
        if len(contour) < stdev/3:
            # Appending small contours to an array
            filtered_cont.append(contour)
    return filtered_cont

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])

# Getting image dimensions
h,w,l = img.shape
size = (w,h)

gray_image=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(gray_image,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

noisy_contours = denoise(contours)
# Filtering out noise
cv2.drawContours(img,noisy_contours,-1,color=(0,0,0),thickness=cv2.FILLED)
# Saving denoised image
cv2.imwrite('contours-denoised.png',img)


filtered=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged=cv2.Canny(filtered,20,100)

# Creating blank black image
blank_image= np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)

# Finding contours from denoised image
contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# Sorting contours from large to small
contours.sort(key=len,reverse=True)

# Initializing video output
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.mp4',fourcc, 10, size)

# Iterating through contours
for  cont in contours:
    # Drawing one contour and filling it with white
    cv2.drawContours(blank_image, [cont], -1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    # Writing image into video stream
    out.write(blank_image)
out.release()

# Saving image
cv2.imwrite('contours-denoised-drawn.png',blank_image)
```

### [image: Original image]
Source image

### [image: Original image denoised]
Source image denoised

### [image: Denoised image after Canny edge detection]
Canny edges

### [image: Drawn version of denoised image]
Drawn version of denoised image (after Canny)

Comment: Can you add the image after canny?

Comment: @Ema I added an image to my post. 3rd picture shows the Canny edges.

Comment: OpenCV drawcontours decide which area between the contours should be filled by the hierarchy condition of the contours, the step of denoise which removes small contours may effect the hierarchy condition of the contours, but i thought you already get what you want at line "cv2.imwrite('contours-denoised.png',img)" though.

Comment: @Ema I tried commenting out the denoising function, but the result is still messed up. And you're right, I want my image to look like how it looks after cv2.imwrite('contours-denoised.png',img), but I want to be able to draw it one contour at a time. So when I insert those images into a video, it will look like the computer is drawing the lines one at a time.